# Simplest approach to 'inject' database name (and other values) for each client app (B2B) at build time (debug and release) from single codebase?

Tags: flutter, build, environment-variables, key, fastlane

I am creating a B2B app, each client has its own database name as databases are seperate from one client to the next, there's no central repository for security sake. For instance, Corporation A's database is 'corpa' and Corporation B's database is 'corpb'...Corporation A and Corporation B use the same appbase, they only need a few 'configuration' values such as the database name above which are unique to their setup.

I've never published an app which requires specific configuration values, could someone please push me in the best direction for a method to build these apps (including debug test builds) with their specific configuration values included? I'd like it so that when I build debug or release of Corporation A's app it includes the configuration value key/pair of {'dbname':'corpa'}.

I am utilizing Fastlane locally for CD, but I don't necessarily need to rely on Fastlane (hopefully) to do this. I would like to use the simplest approach and one that won't mix up configuration values between Corporation A and Corporation B.

Much appreciated, if you can supply a brief example or documentation that shows such you're my hero!

**tl;dr - When building debug or release I need to inject the dbname as a key value pair such as {'dbname':'corpa'} for Corporation A or {'dbname':'corpb'} for Corporation B. There will be around 50 different corporate apps built from the same codebase, each will need specific configuration values such as the 'dbname'. How can this be done locally?**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wanting to do run or build environment variables the answer is to utilize `dart-define` following the example here:
https://dartcode.org/docs/using-dart-define-in-flutter/